# PHP image upload issue. Uploads images that are web optimised but not the original image

Tags: php, html, ajax, file-upload, w3c

I am having this problem of uploading images using PHP. All of the images are JPEG

I have several files copied to my desktop from camera and iphone. All of the files are various size from 800Kb to 6MB.

Non of the above files that are from camera or iphone would upload to my server not because of  MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE as I have already configured it to be 30M (30MB).

Now I opened two of these image (size 5.6MB and 1.9MB) in Photoshop and saved them for web images. Both of this image size stayed same (as I forced them to stay same). Now When I try to upload this photoshop optimised images onto my server, they upload successfully. I just can't understand what the problem is here. Are the images from iphone and camera has some restriction or a specific header that is restricting the upload? Please note that I copied the images to my desktop before uploading and not trying to upload straight from the device folder.

Here is the html and php coding of the file:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

if (file_exists("image_test/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    "image_test/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    echo "Stored in: " . "image_test/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
}
  }
  else
 {
   echo "Invalid file";
 }
 } 
?>

<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_test.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

if someone has an answer or hint towards this problem then I would greatly appreciate it.

Kind regards

Comment: No, I am using windows. My server is apache.

Comment: Are you successfully receiving the files server-side in your `$_FILES` array, or does the request never complete? What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: The page just refreshes and nothing really happens. I am using upload script from W3C. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp
I am using the code right at the bottom of the page.

Comment: It says invalid file. The file doesn't get uploaded to the server

Comment: If you are using that code verbatim it has a file size condition: `$_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000` (20000 bytes)

Comment: I have removed that code. As I said above I am able to upload same file that has gone through photoshop and has a file size for 3.5MB but cannot upload the original image.

Comment: Do a `var_dump( $_FILES ); exit;` at the start of your script. Then try uploading a photo that works and one that doesn't. Post the output here.

Comment: Show us your HTML and PHP code, it will be easier for us.

Comment: My code has now been pasted into original post

Comment: var dump output for successfully upload image:
Upload: P1000125_test.jpg
Type: image/jpeg
Size: 3417.4580078125 Kb
Temp file: /var/tmp/phpV2ztyu
Stored in: image_test/P1000125_test.jpgarray(1) { ["file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(17) "P1000125_test.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(18) "/var/tmp/phpV2ztyu" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(3499477) } }

Comment: var dump output for unsuccessful  image:
Invalid filearray(1) { ["file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(12) "P1000125.JPG" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(18) "/var/tmp/phpUMy0WO" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(5916160) } }

Comment: The correct Apache variables you will need to look at are `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`; It sounds like you correctly have the first one set - check the latter; normally it's `2M` by default (I think).

Comment: My php.ini file has: memory_limit = 30M;
post_max_size = 64M;
upload_max_filesize = 64M;

Comment: It cannot be php settings because both files that I am uploading is same size. The only difference is that the one file hasn't gone through photoshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, modified the top section of the above code as below:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")))
{
```

Basically, it was due to end(). Tried to use the same script on localhost server whic started giving me an error as following:

**Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\search\php\loader\csvFileUploader1.php on line 9**

This lead me to research on it which gave me a solution that it is due to the end function in line 4.

Thanks everyone for trying to help me. I do appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0):

*Attention!* Filenames might be in `UPPERCASE`.

try to replace

```
 $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
```

with

```
 $extension = strtolower(end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"])));
```

best regards.